# Настройка nginx как реверс-прокси c подменой поддомена

Tags: nginx, прокси

Возникла необходимость на IP-адресе 1.1.1.1 поднять на nix-машине nginx, который бы представлялся как сайт site1.company.tld, но при этом отдавал контент, запрошенный с IP-адреса 2.2.2.2 (там стоит IIS, который отдаёт сайт site2.company.tld). Опускаю всю корпоративную лирику про сетевухи и какими каналами идёт трафик, считаем, что оба сервера торчат в интернет, DNS записи есть возможность задавать в своей зоне любые какие надо.

Многократно подымал сервера в конфигурации, когда за nginx локально стоит другой вебсервер, скажем apache и не было никаких проблем в проксировании:

```
location / {
    #proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
    proxy_redirect off;
    log_not_found off;
    #proxy_set_header Host $host;
    #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    proxy_pass http://2.2.2.2:8080/;
    proxy_set_header Host site2.company.tld;
}
```

Казалось бы -- поменять IP и хедеры и готово. Nginx, он же как раз и есть по сути обычный реверс-прокси, который запрашивает контент у бекенда, представляясь клиентом, а потом отдаёт дальше посетителю.

Однако, не зашло.

Во-первых, пришлось на время экспериментов перевести внутренний портал на 2.2.2.2 на http (раньше стоял https only), так как я помню, что nginx умеет общаться с бекендом только по HTTP 1.0 (даже не HTTP 1.1) и не уверен точно, но не умеет https бекенды (иначе бы получился бы классический man in the middle)

Во-вторых, попытки смены заголовков Host и X-Forwarded-For почему-то не приводят к успеху: запрос либо уходит на 2.2.2.2 как к site1 (а там его нет, есть site2), либо уходит на 1.1.1.1

До в-третьих ("нужно как-то скрывать proxy_hide_header факт проксирования") даже речь не дошло. (Админы ушли и начали прорабатывать альтернативные варианты на базе squid, а я задумался)

Вот какие у меня вопросы по возможности создания такого прокси на базе nginx:

1. Можно ли вообще собрать такую конфигурацию при помощи nginx или вот именно такая подмена домена site1 -> site2 невозможна? Если невозможна -- то почему?
2. Если такая конфигурация возможна, то может ли кто-то показать схематически основу конфига, чтобы была возможность разобраться и сделать свой конкретный?
3. Может ли nginx общаться с бекендом по HTTPS или только по HTTP?

Comment: Вполне себе умеет https-бэкенды. Никакого MitM-преимущества это не дает, для реализации MitM-атаки у злоумышленника на руках уже должен быть контроль над dns и валидный сертификат, запрет nginx на проксирование https здесь был бы как мертвому припарки.

Comment: «я помню, что nginx умеет общаться с бекендом только по HTTP 1.0» — плохо помните, в документации написано про `proxy_http_version 1.1;`

Comment: @etki Хм, логично. С учётом того, что у меня есть возможности выпуска каких угодно сертификатов внутри своих доменов -- я могу как угодно ПО настроить, лишь бы само ПО умело такое проксировать.

Comment: @andreymal Да, оказывается в новых версиях есть такая возможность proxy_http_version: с 1.1.4, а я как запомнил сведения пятилетней давности, так и не актуализировал.

Comment: Вообще, я сейчас попробовал написать конфигурацию аналогичную данной с `proxy_pass https://151.101.1.69; proxy_set_header Host ru.stackoverflow.com;` и у меня всё работает :)

Comment: @andreymal Точно, работает ruso, только что запроксировал. Наверное что-то админы накосячили с настройками сетевух. Вопрос можно закрывать: "вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой.", ну или если не лень - то можете написать ответ -- приму галкой.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, IIS в плане бэкенда проксирования никак не отличается от других серверов.

Во-вторых, ничто не мешает вам добавить в список биндингов IIS сайт `site1.company.tld` - тогда и подменять Host не понадобится:

[image: Скриншот]

Это при условии что IIS вообще смотрит на заголовок Host - там же по умолчанию любые домены одинаково обрабатываются.

Рекомендую так и сделать, потому что некоторые библиотеки могут при подмененном доменном имени работать неправильно. К примеру, WCF при проксировании со сменой доменного имени отдает wsdl со внутренними биндингами, их там внутри никакой proxy_redirect не поменяет на правильные.

Comment: Павел, спасибо за советы по WCF (он там есть, да), думаю пригодятся на будущее при допиливании портала. Самый простой вариант - навесить алиас к сожалению был сразу отброшен: портал похоронен в глубине корпоративных ресурсов и разрешено только выставлять через отдельный публикатор.

Comment: @AK так вы его и выставите через отдельный публикатор. Только перед этим расскажите сайту что у него существует этот самый "отдельный публикатор". Это - самый безопасный способ, все остальные способы чреваты глюками, который будут исправляться костылями.

Comment: @AK я же не говорю что надо IP-адрес в DNS прописывать или второй адрес давать серверу.