# 2 сайта 1 домен. редирект без замены домена

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Здравствйте! 
есть 2 домена и 1 сайт. необходимо сделать некие "редирект" но без замены домена. то есть что бы по переходу по ссылке сайт1.ком, пользователя перенаправляло на сайт2.ком но при этом в браузере отображалось по прежнему имя сайт1.ком.

когда то такое делал. но не могу вспомнить как. что бы не дублировать сайт дважды.

даже уточню. главная страница у сайтов будет разная. но далее все страницы будут одинаковые. как это реализовать?

Comment: `ServerAlias` или [проксирование](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/622840/213987).

Comment: супер! спасибо. вопрос дальше. как сделать что бы главная страница не перебрасывалась потому что они разные. а перебрасывалась только все что после /

Comment: я не понял, что вы сделали (я выше писал две альтернативы, какую из них вы выбрали не знаю, я не телепат), а кроме того я не знаю, что у вас в коде написано. Возможно, стоит задать новый вопрос. Без знания как у вас устроено -- вообще мало что можно рекомендовать вслепую. Только наугад если.

Comment: <VirtualHost domain1.local:80>

    DocumentRoot    "\domain1.local\web"
    ServerName      "domain1.local"
    ServerAlias     "domain1.local" domain2.local
 
</VirtualHost>

Comment: нужно что бы при заходе на домен2. главная страница оставалась его. а при дальнейшем перемещении перебрасывать все на домен1/внутр_страница

Comment: Не надо писать код в комментариях -- что за неуважение к читающим? Сидеть и разбираться, где переносы строк.

Answer (score 1):

На первоначальный вопрос я вам дал ответ, двумя способами:

> либо `ServerAlias` либо
>   [проксирование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/622840/213987).

Вы пошли по первому способу:

```
<VirtualHost domain1.local:80> 
   DocumentRoot "\domain1.local\web" 
   ServerName "domain1.local" 
   ServerAlias "domain1.local" domain2.local 
</VirtualHost>
```

Окей, не вопрос.

Но сейчас у вас новый вопрос, созданный путём редактирования старого.

Так вот новый вопрос способом через ServerAlias не решается, апач для такого не предназначен. Ставьте перед апачем nginx и в нём прописывайте правила проксирования. Для этого просто объявите две разные локации, одну проксировать, вторую показывать с какого-то другого скрипта.

Comment: та это я просто тестирую на локалке. опенсервер. а так то у меня VPS на линуксе. там возможносте больше. спасибо. буду пробовать разобратся

Answer (score 0):

В панели хостинга (cPanel,ISPManager...) в разделе `Домены` настройте Addon Domain для домена `сайт1.ком`(не забудьте вставить NS вашего хостинга на котором находится сайт), тем самым будет открываться ваш сайт без смены домена.

ЗЫ при редиректе доменное имя меняется, так как перенаправляет на основной домен.

Comment: простой редирект я знаю как сделать. меня именно интересует то что я описал. я так лет 7 назад делал.